# SQL query: merge 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-merge

I need to generate a SQL query for the following case:

First table:

```
|column1|
|-------|
|A      |
|B      |
```

Second table:

```
|column2|
|-------|
|1      |
|2      |
|3      |
|4      |
```

I want to create a query so the result will be like this:

```
|column1|column2|
|-------|-------|
|A      |1      |
|A      |2      |
|A      |3      |
|A      |4      |
|B      |1      |
|B      |2      |
|B      |3      |
|B      |4      |
```

Appreciate any answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cross join between the two tables:

```sql
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2
FROM FirstTable t1
CROSS JOIN SecondTable t2
ORDER BY t1.column1, t2.column2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Cartesian product

```
SELECT FirstTable.col_x, SecondTable.col_x
FROM FirstTable
CROSS JOIN SecondTable;
```